# List files not tracked by Git LFS

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm initializing a new Git repo with a huge pile of files. The repo is using [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/). I want to ensure that I've told LFS to track all files that should be handled, before I make my first commit.

I see that [`git lfs ls-files`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-ls-files.1.ronn) will list all the files that ARE tracked by LFS. However, (a) I want the opposite: all files in the repo that aren't tracked by LFS (and are in `.gitignore`), and (b) this command only works [after you have committed files](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/700).

Does anyone have some git-fu or Ubuntu-fu to list all the files in the repo that aren't ignored and aren't matched by the track patterns in the various `.gitattribute` files Git LFS uses?

---

*The closest I've come is this command that lists files in the repo over 100kB, and then manually scanning all the files and hope that I've them covered by a tracking pattern.*

```
find . -type f -exec du -Sha -t 100000 {} +
```

Answer (score 13):

Even though the question concerns files that have *not* been commited, let me suggest a solution to list the files tracked by git but not git-lfs **after commit**, which you can do by concatenating the list of files tracked by git (`git ls-files`) with those tracked by git-lfs (`git lfs ls-files | cut -d' ' -f3-`) and then only take the files that are unique in this list:

```
{ git ls-files && git lfs ls-files | cut -d' ' -f3-; } | sort | uniq -u
```

After which you could edit your commit (`git rm --cached` and `git commit --amend`) if you notice a file that has sneaked in...

At the pre-commit stage, proceeding by watching the untracked files list and successively using `git lfs track` and `git add` should be quite safe.

Beware, that empty files are not considered LFS objects by the specification, so they will not be listed by `git lfs ls-files`

Comment: The range in the `cut` command (`-f3`) should be `-f3-` in case there's a space in one of the paths.

Comment: A git-alias version of this that works regardless of where you are in the directory structure of a git repository: `  lfs-untracked = "!_() { ((git ls-files | egrep \"^${GIT_PREFIX}\") && (git lfs ls-files ${GIT_PREFIX:+-I ${GIT_PREFIX}} | cut -d' ' -f3-)) | sort | uniq -u ; }; _"`

Comment: Sorted by file size: `({ git ls-files && git lfs ls-files | cut -d' ' -f3-; } | sort | uniq -u) | xargs stat -c '%s %n' | numfmt --to=iec | sort -h`

Answer (score 1):

Let me give some ideas:

To get a list of all files in your repository:

```
find . -type f > all.txt
```

To get a list of all files that will be tracked by LFS:

```
set -f; for f in $(cat .gitattributes | cut -d ' ' -f 1); do find . -name $f; done > lfs.txt
```

To get a list of all files that will NOT be tracked by LFS:

```
grep -f lfs.txt -F -w -v all.txt > non-lfs.txt
```